# Cropping instead of clipping

Tags: wpf, xaml, crop, clip

When clipping a WPF element using a RectangleGeometry, part of the original element will never be shown. Can I then crop to this part of the visual, so that the remainder is stretched to fill the parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can clip and put it in a [`Viewbox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox.aspx) to stretch as needed.

Comment: But then part of the background behind what is clipped gets stretched.

Comment: @FrankRazenberg: I do not quite understand what you mean, could you give a concrete example?